# Как обновить `pip` в Termux?

Tags: python, pip, termux

Есть ли на данный момент рабочий способ обновить `pip` в Termux? Кто пользовался, знает, что обычным способом `pip install --upgrade pip` обновить нельзя, так как сам Termux запрещает, так как это может убить весь пакет Python..

Я пытаюсь установить библиотеки, и постоянно вырезаюсь в проблемы, которые обновление `pip` вероятно бы решило. Столько костылей из интернета уже перепробовал, и до сих пор ошибки возникают.

Comment: С 99% уверенности можно утверждать, что — нет, не решило бы

Comment: Попробуйте `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Скажете, получится или нет.

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard нет, не работает. Termux по-прежнему блокирует.

Answer (score 0):

Обновить `pip` на `Termux` можно в виртуальном окружении.

```
$ python -m venv {название}
$ source {название}/bin/activate
```